# Excel VBA Autofilter Values Not Equal To Asterisk (*)

Tags: excel, vba, asterisk, autofilter

The problem I'm having is that i need to be able to filter for everything in specific columns that are not equal to "*". Also, I can't just filter simply by blanks as i have multiple values in the columns.

So far i have tried:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$5000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*"
```

And

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$5000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>" & "*"
```

Is this possible given the unique nature of the asterisk? Any solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: `"*"` must be escaped. Otherwise, it is count like wildcard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `~` to escape the wildcard:

```
Criteria1:="<>~*"
```